# Python 3.7 : Why is only the last item in a list printing?

Tags: list, while-loop, python-3.7

I am self-studying "Python Crash Course" 2nd edition and I have come upon a problem that I am unable to solve. I have reread previous areas of the book, searched the internet and search other SO answers.

The official book answer uses a dictionary but I am trying to use a list.

The program should ask for input, add the input to a list and continue to repeat until told to stop. When told to stop, the entire list should be printed.

The problem that I am running into is that only the last item in the list in printing.

Instead of giving the answer, please just give me a hint so that I can truly learn.

Thanks,

chadrick

```
active = True
while active == True:
    places = []
    place = input("\nIf you could visit one place in the world, where would you go? ")
    places.append(place)
    repeat = input("Would you like to let another person respond? (yes/no) ")
    if repeat == 'no':
        print(places)
        active = False
```

Comment: Just move the places = [] out of while loop :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you're resetting the list back to empty for every iteration.

try the following:

```
active = True
places = []
while active == True:
    place = input("\nIf you could visit one place in the world, where would you go? ")
    places.append(place)
    repeat = input("Would you like to let another person respond? (yes/no) ")
    if repeat == 'no':
        print(places)
        active = False
```

Also, since `active` is a boolean, you just need to do `while active:`

So:

```
active = True
places = []
while active:
    place = input("\nIf you could visit one place in the world, where would you go? ")
    places.append(place)
    repeat = input("Would you like to let another person respond? (yes/no) ")
    if repeat == 'no':
        print(places)
        active = False
```

Comment: Aha! Oh course. When I said that "places = []", it set the list to a blank list. Since it was inside the loop, every time the loop ran, the list got reset to a blank list. Putting it outside the loop caused it to be set to empty only at the beginning. Thank you so much!!